# How do I copy whole tables from ODBC source to SQL server using c# .Net without specifying columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, copy, odbc

This will be in C#

I would like to do this without specifying column names as will be multiple tables.

Will be a nightly scheduled task, truncating old then writing new.

I have a working odbc connection and sql connection.

One thought is to use dapper but cast to an object instead of a model class. Would this work.

Comment: I don't know about dapper, but you could try performing a `SELECT *...` into a C# data table - afterwards you can loop through it, evaluating the column names and corrsponding values as you do, and then create SQL Commands which you fire from within your C# code... depending on the size of your tables this should work pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

After populating a datatable via odbc, you can write to sql db with

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = dataTable.TableName;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

No need to specify column names